# How to create a Image from a Docker Container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

As I want to make my existing application as a Docker images. And I have to install lot of installation which I can't do using Docker file. How I am doing is I created a Docker container with OS, and log-in in to that and I Installed all the software I needed. Now I want to make the image out of it.

Comment: As Victor says, you should really solve the root issue (not being able to install it with Dockerfile) instead of using this workaround. Because later, no one will know the state of your image, what components are installed, how it is configured etc.

Comment: @Vinany If you can share the steps that are troubling you in another question we might be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `docker commit`.

Check out [Docker commit official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/):

> docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
>
> --author , -a     Author (e.g., “John Hannibal Smith hannibal@a-team.com”)
>
> --change , -c     Apply Dockerfile instruction to the created image
>
> --message , -m        Commit message
>
> --pause , -p  true    Pause container during commit

Note this important remark:

> By default, the container being committed and its processes will be paused while the image is committed. This reduces the likelihood of encountering data corruption during the process of creating the commit.

**However this is not the best practice.** You should build everything using a dockerfile for maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

`docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]`

See [the doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) for more detailed explanation

---

Unless you have very specific need which prevents using [`Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to build your image, you should prefer the `Dockerfile` with the [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) command